# How do i get the auto increment field mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can i get the auto increment field name using `ALTER TABLE`

Or

Is there any other idea to get auto increment field

Comment: What are trying to do?

Comment: Uh, so you want to determine the name of the AUTO_INCREMENT field, if any? Programmatically?

Comment: I want to fetch the auto increment field name from table so based on that field i need to update data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get table details something like this

```
$res = $mysqli->query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename');

while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
     if ($row['Extra'] == 'auto_increment')
     echo 'Field with auto_increment = '.$row['Field'];
     if ($row['Key'] == 'PRI')
     echo 'Field with primary key = '.$row['Field'];
}
```

Comment: You could append `WHERE Extra LIKE '%auto_increment%'`.

Comment: That's very true @MartinTörnwall. Here I just wanted to demo a generic way of getting all details of a table. Your point is promptly valid for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use information_schema database for that

```
SELECT column_name, column_key, extra
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'yourdatabase'
AND table_name = 'yourtable'
AND extra = 'auto_increment'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the information_schema database you can find the auto increment value for a table in the **TABLES** table. The **COLUMNS** table contains details of each column, and the extra field on this table will show auto_increment for auto incrementing columns.